# PHP for download vcf on mobile for auto load on contact app

Tags: php, android, vcf-vcard

a php file for downalod a most complete vcf correct AUTO loaded on android sys

re-edit th eproblem info

If I launch the php directly on the browser http:site/nameoffile.php it works correctly like this, the result is fine by me:

1. The android browser asks to save the file
2. then the browser asks to open the file
3. yes, ok
4. the android browser makes the android contact app read all the info correctly

But if I put the http:site/name of file.php link as http:site/nameoffile.php the file is downloaded as
nameoffile.php.vcf the browser append vcf

I want the file in android to download and launch as the direct link

NOTE AFTER USE
the file is downloaded yes as php but it isnt automatically launched to contacts app.

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$BaseName.php"")
```

CODE MODIFIED v02

````
<?php
# Send correct headers      
header("Content-type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8");
# header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test-vcard.php"');
# header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
# header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$BaseName.php"")

# Set variables for contact information
$logo = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
$suffix = "ghost";
$given_name = "John";
$family_name = "Doe";
$title = "ghostbuster";
$mobile = "66605852222";
$email = "ghost@gmail.live.com";
$org = "ghostbuster";
$note = "seek and destroy";
$url = "ghostbuster.com";
$adr = "nowere";
$formatted_name = "$given_name $family_name $suffix ";

# Output vCard data
echo "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n";
echo "VERSION:4.0\r\n";
echo "LOGO:$logo\r\n";
echo "N:$family_name;$given_name;$suffix;\r\n";
echo "FN:$family_name;$given_name;$suffix;\r\n";
echo "TEL;CELL;VOICE:$mobile;\r\n";
echo "EMAIL;PREF:$email\r\n";
echo "ORG:$org\r\n";
# echo "GEO:$geo\r\n";
echo "URL:$url\r\n";
echo "NOTE:$note\r\n";
echo "TITLE:$title\r\n";
echo "ADR;WORK;POSTAL:$adr\r\n";
echo "END:VCARD\r\n";
?>```
````

Comment: You can set a Content-disposition header to control the filename

Comment: Please write me the line and where should I insert it so as not to mess up? Thank you

Comment: Anywhere near the `header("Content-type` line would be fine, it's just another HTTP response header. You can find plenty of examples online of what it should look like, already, if you do a bit of basic research. Try it. If you get stuck after that, [edit] your question to show your attempt and explain what went wrong. We're happy to help at stackoverflow when necessary, but we don't need to spend time repeating ourselves endlessly on things that are well-known. Really the first thing you should have done after reading my comment was to google "php content-disposition header" or similar.

Comment: yes I searched for "php content-disposition header" but I apologize, I understand a little bit of html and css, for me php is arabic, in fact I did a copy paste and tested with tests for 3 days. Thanks anyway, I'll look into it further

Comment: Well like I said, if you can show me what you tried, and explain what the issue was, I can help you to fix it.

Comment: If you only need to link to those from within your own site, then you can also simply use the [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download) attribute on your links to specify what file name should be suggested to the user.

Comment: from this 

    header("Content-type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8");

i set this

    #header("Content-type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test-vcard.php"');

but file, on adnroid, was download with a html extension
i will search well code for android for
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="???.php

Comment: Bear in mind that a header is just a suggestion for the browser to follow. It doesn't mean the receiving application will definitely use it. So maybe the android application is ignoring the header. Obviously we cannot see what code is in use there. Or are you just talking about a web browser running on Android?

Comment: P.S. As you can see, the code in the comments is not formatted and is hard to read. Please _always_ [edit] your question when you have code to share, or significant updates to make. Then you can format it properly, and show it in context. Thanks.